# material ui wrapper export interface casting any type in typescript (react)

Tags: typescript, import, export, material-ui

i use react in typescript.

and i had a problem with export. I'm making an interface that wraps `Material-ui`.

for example,

**Wrapping.tsx**

```
import { default as Component, ComponentProps as MProps
}from '@material-ui/core/SomeComponent;

export interface MyPorps extends MProps {}
export default MyComponent: React.FC<MyPorps> = props => {
   some of render code
}
```

**index.ts**

```
import MyComponent from './wrapping'
import MyProps from './wrapping'
export default MyComponent;
export MyProps;
```

**Usage.tsx**

```
import MyComponent, { MyProps }from '@wrapping;
// waring: 'MyProps' has declared, but not use.

export default Myusage: React.FC<MyPorps> = props => {
    let data: MyProps = { 
       // MyProps has got error MyProps is any type
       // error code: 'MyProps ' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)
    }
}
```

i dont know why `MyProps` recognize `any` type
and `MyProps` is different both `let data` and `import { MyProps }`

is it any problem my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount solution. haha sorry for late posting

the answer is

```
import MyComponent from './wrapping'
export default MyComponent;
export * from './MyProps';
```

`export * from './MyProps'` is good way for default export with other export things